# How to overlay points/bubbles on Google Maps to produce animation

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to visualize some mobile logs and I want to overlay points/bubbles on Google Maps in corresponding time/location. Sort of like this animation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6EaMQDHu7Q

I know one can use Google Fusion Tables API to plot the dots but I am not pretty sure about how to produce an animation like this. Should I wrap my visualization code (like [one in the Fusion Table doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-heatmap)) into `setInterval` or something?

My current tools of choice is `d3` and `Google Maps`. If there are better tools to achieve my goal please also feel free to suggest better approach.

Comment: This is a very broad question. I suggest that you have a look at the many examples for D3 and start coding it up. You're likely to get much better answers if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll code up a static version first.